# Как проверить Exception в тестовом проекте xUnit?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, xunit

Вот такое определение требует явно указать точный тип исключения:

```cs
Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => {...});
```

... и, например `System.ArgumentException`, уже не пропускается.

Есть ли простой способ проверки любого исключения?

PS: API Документацию [они (xunit)](https://xunit.net/) так и не сделали.

Comment: так логично же что Assert.Throws требует точный тип исключения. твой метод может выкидывать их множество. у некоторых бизнес логика построина на том чтобы выкидывать специфическое, свое описанное, исключение и потом на уровнях выше его обрабатывать (например EntityNotFoundException или CurrencyConverException). Следовательно тебе надо будет проверять каждое из них.

Comment: @PeterLavreniuk У меня есть методы `Чтото(...)` и `Unchecked_Чтото(...)`. Вторые используются в целях оптимизации без проверки и "подгона" параметров. Там может быть несколько стандартных(не моих) исключений и какое совершенно неважно.

Comment: тогда надо делать свой экстеншен. там не сложная имплементация Assert.Throws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, вот так надо, чтобы поймать любого наследника указанного исключения

```
Assert.ThrowsAny<Exception>(() => {...});
```

Comment: Да, именно это я и искал. Не знаю как так нелепо я мог просмотреть такую "автоподсказку", да еще с документированным описанием _or a derived exception(с)_